# The clip distance in edit mode keeps resetting

Tags: edit-mode

[image: sensei format object mode]
When I enter edit mode the far clip distance is 7.5m
I set it to 500m [image: changed to 500m], exit edit mode, re-enter edit mode and it goes back to 7.5 [image: back to object mode, note reset]
The same when in object mode except it resets to 100m no matter what value I set it to.[image: sensei format edit mode]

can somebody tell me the solution to this, I updated to 2.79 last night this was not happening until I reopened blender this morning

EDIT: screenshots rectified

Comment: If you can reproduce that behaviour and it happens on the recent build report a bug at https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: Redo the screenshots without all the relevant panels closed. The transform panel for example.

Comment: @Haunt_House I have tried to reproduce the result with more visible information, such as the grid(partially) and default object vanishing
I am able to work without sensei format but I'd rather not give up the improved workflow that it offers

Comment: Never heard of sensei format before. Is an addon causing this?